# What is the best practice to write unit test and skip some line of code within method in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have java code simply do below steps:

- Getting json response from url (I would like to skip this and instead use pre defined variable for test purposes)
- Check some conditions (which i would like to perform unit test)
- Execute put method to kill applications using rest-api (I would like to skip this because I do not want to kill any application while testing conditions)

Here is my method which I would like to perform unit test:

```
public void checkYarnApplications() throws IOException {

    // Get json object from yarn rest-api
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    URL getJsonUrl1 = new URL(getUrlAddress());

    Map<String,Object> map1 = mapper.readValue(getJsonUrl1,Map.class);

    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(map1);

    // Initialize stringbuilder to build slack message
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Iterate through number of existing yarn application
    for (int i = 0; i < j.getJSONObject("apps").getJSONArray("app").length(); i++){

        JSONObject name = j.getJSONObject("apps")
                .getJSONArray("app")
                .getJSONObject(i);

        String state = name.get("state").toString();

        // Check if application is in Running state
        if (state.equals("RUNNING")){

            // Get elapsed time for each running application and convert it to hour
            int elapsed_time = name.getInt("elapsedTime")/3600000;
            // Get application name
            String app_name = name.get("name").toString();
            // Get application queue_name
            String queue_name = name.get("queue").toString();
            // Get application user_name
            String user_name = name.get("user").toString();

            // Check if pyspark applications last longer than specified time in config.properties
            if (app_name.startsWith("pyspark-shell") && elapsed_time > getSparkCheckTime()){
                String app_id = name.get("id").toString();
                String infoMessageSpark = "pyspark application " + app_id + " has been killed because it takes longer than " + getSparkCheckTime() + " hours";
                logger.info(infoMessageSpark);
                logger.info(name.toString());
                // Kill yarn application
                URL url = new URL(String.format("%s%s/state?user.name=atlasapp",getUrlAddress(),app_id));
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                http.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                http.setDoOutput(true);
                http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                String data = "{\"state\": \"KILLED\"}";

                byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
                stream.write(out);

                System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
                http.disconnect();
                // Add info message to slackmessage string builder
                stringBuilder.append(infoMessageSpark);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
            // Check if self_bi applications last longer than specified time in config.properties
            else if (!queue_name.equals("yarn-system") && !queue_name.equals("hudi") && !queue_name.equals("hepsistream") &&
                    !app_name.equals("Bzip2Hdfs") && !user_name.equals("spark") && !user_name.equals("yarn-ats") &&
                    !app_name.startsWith("pyspark-shell") && !queue_name.equals("llap") && elapsed_time > getappCheckTime()){
                String app_id = name.get("id").toString();
                String infoMessageSb = queue_name + " application, " + app_id + " has been killed because it takes longer than "
                        + getappCheckTime() + " hours. Elapsed Time:" + elapsed_time;
                logger.info(infoMessageSb);
                logger.info(name.toString());
                // Kill yarn application
                URL url = new URL(String.format("%s%s/state?user.name=atlasapp",getUrlAddress(),app_id));
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                http.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                http.setDoOutput(true);
                http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                String data = "{\"state\": \"KILLED\"}";

                byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
                stream.write(out);

                System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
                http.disconnect();
                // Add info message to slackmessage string builder
                stringBuilder.append(infoMessageSb);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
            // Check if any application except hudi, llap last longer than specified time in config.properties and send them to slack channel
            else if (!queue_name.equals("hudi") && !queue_name.equals("llap") && !queue_name.equals("hepsistream") &&
                    !queue_name.equals("yarn-system") && !user_name.equals("yarn-ats") &&
                    !app_name.startsWith("pyspark-shell") && !app_name.equals("Bzip2Hdfs") && !user_name.equals("spark") &&
                    elapsed_time > getCheckTime()){
                logger.info("Application_id: " + name.get("id").toString() + " is running longer than " +  getCheckTime() + " hours");
                String textMessage ="Elapsed time: " + elapsed_time + " hours" + ", " +
                        "Application_Id: " + name.get("id").toString() + ", " +
                        "Username: " + name.get("user").toString() + ", " +
                        "Queuename:" + name.get("queue").toString() + ", " +
                        "Usage:" + name.get("clusterUsagePercentage").toString();
                stringBuilder.append(textMessage);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I would like to use some pre defined json string which will be equal to string I receive as a response using http connection. And only would like to check if - else-if conditions if they are working properly. And also would like to skip some line of code to kill some applications if conditions are met. So simply I would like to implement some assertequal method to compare infoMessage strings(which you can see in my code) only.
I found some mockito methods to mock complete method but here I want to skip some line of code inside of method and I couldnt find any example regarding this requirements. Any help and directions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your best choice is to apply the *Single Responsibility Pattern* and extract your `if/else` block into a separate Method (preferably in a separate class) so you can test it as an *unit in isolation*. This (separate class) would also allow to replace the *condition checker* with a *Mock* when testing the rest of the logic.

Comment: Seems like logical thank you for your suggestion, I will definitely go that way since it is best practice, but may i ask is there any way to do that without changing my code? Even if it is not best practice at all.

Comment: *"is there any way to do that without changing my code? Even if it is not best practice at all."* **--** I don't see any. After all Java insists in the order of execution...